# How can one completely unload background.js in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that injects a number of scripts into a page, performs some operations, and updates the badge text and color with the results. The badge text is updated *only* for the current, active tab.

When I click a link and go to another page in the *same tab*, the badge is reset to its virgin state. However, background.js is still alive and well, maintaining state variables from the previous page.

In manifest.json, I have explicitly set persistent: false.

```
"background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
```

For now I have brute-forced it with an event listener:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.runtime.reload();
});
```

and this effectively unloads the extension, but I'd love to know why on an URL change background.js persists and the badge changes do not. What am I missing?

==========

EDIT:
Didn't mention in earlier description that I am using ports for communication between the background script and content scripts. However, from: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

*You may want to find out when a connection is closed, for example if you are maintaining separate state for each open port. For this you can listen to the runtime.Port.onDisconnect event. This event is fired either when the other side of the channel manually calls runtime.Port.disconnect, or **when the page containing the port is unloaded (for example if the tab is navigated).** onDisconnect is guaranteed to be fired only once for any given port.*

A navigation change should close the port and unload the background script no?

---

Comment: A navigation can spin up a new instance of your content script. There's not enough code here to understand the problem completely

Answer (score 0):

Nonpersistent background page aka [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) is unloaded after approx. 5 seconds of inactivity.

> Once the event page has been idle a short time (a few seconds), the runtime.onSuspend event is dispatched. The event page has a few more seconds to handle this event before it is forcibly unloaded. If during this time an event occurs which would normally cause the event page to be loaded, the suspend is canceled and the runtime.onSuspendCanceled event is dispatched.

Comment: That's the opposite of what I'm describing: it *doesn't* go into suspendMode.

Comment: It *does* go after 5 seconds of the *event page inactivity*.